# Facebook Messenger information download is missing JSON files?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I downloaded my information through Facebook (Settings > JSON format > Messages) but when I unzipped the folder I couldn't find any JSON files. I could navigate to individual conversations (messages > inbox > *person a*) but those subfolders only contained the media we exchanged like photos, GIFs, videos, etc. Is there a separate way to obtain the JSON files? I searched through the whole download and couldn't find them at all.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue. I think it's a technical issue on Facebook's end.

Comment: I see, is there a way to contact them to obtain these files?

Comment: I have had better luck by reducing the interval being requested (eg. only requesting the last month of data). None of my attempts to contact Facebook have gotten anywhere.